# setInterval cannot be used into other functions

Tags: javascript, setinterval

After solving a problem about how to display data of an array each XXX seconds with setIterval funcion with the code:

```
var iterations = 0,
    data = ['a','bbbbbbbb','c'],
    interval = setInterval(foo, 4000);

function foo() {
    console.log(data[iterations]);
    iterations++;
    if (iterations >= 4){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }else if(iterations == 1){
        //we want to make time longer in this iteration.
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(foo, 8000);
    }
}
```

I want to clean things and capsulate all this into a function. Problem is, when I insert global vars into a function, foo says all vars are unknown so I've to pass them as attrs. Also, I've changed interval to this in order to detect it, but now it does not work. Displays all data at the same time, seems to ignore setIterval

```
runTest();

function runTest(){
    var iterations = 0,
    data = [1,2,3,4,5],
    maxIterations = 5,
    interval = setInterval(foo(iterations,data,maxIterations),4000);    
}

function foo(iterations,data,maxIterations){
    var sentence = data[iterations];
    var div = d3.select('div').append('p').text(sentence);
    iterations++;
    if (iterations >= maxIterations){
        clearInterval(this);
    }else{
        clearInterval(this);
        interval = setInterval(foo(iterations,data,maxIterations),4000);
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on Chrome debugger flow app seems to be right.

Do you know where the problem is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval needs function as parameter (or a function reference). However, you are passing the result of the function call to foo.

You probably want something like

```
var iterations = 0,
data = [1,2,3,4,5],
maxIterations = 5,
interval = setInterval(function() { foo(iterations,data,maxIterations); }, 4000);
```

Here you are passing a function which in turn calls foo with all necessary parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare the variable 'interval' for the first time inside a function. The variable is not global but localized to that function.

it will work if you first declare all the variables you want to have global, outside any functions.

```
var iterations, maxIterations, data, interval;

runTest();

function runTest(){
    iterations = 0,
    data = [1,2,3,4,5],
    maxIterations = 5,
    interval = setInterval(foo(iterations,data,maxIterations),4000);    
}
```

Be aware that the function foo(), might not change the values of the global variables since you choose the same names for the local variables.